# Radio not playing music through speakers

Tags: subaru, audio, wrx, speakers

I have a 2013 Subaru WRX Limited with the touch screen radio. Recently I realized that my radio lost sound just out of no where one day when my car didn't play music.  The navigation and everything works fine, but no sound. I've had this problem for a week now and I checked the fuse for media and it's fine. What's bugging me is that the speakers work when I'm making a phone call through Bluetooth but when I play a song through it's silent. Nothing from AM/FM radio will work either but it works through AUX input.

I find it very strange and I was wondering what could be causing my speakers to not play music?

Comment: Is this the OEM radio for your WRX?

Comment: Are you sure that the car isn't waiting to play music through the bluetooth connection?

Comment: Oem radio,  and no the car is not waiting for bluetooth because i switch it to radio setting and still nothing

Comment: Have you done any modification to the wire harness or replaced the speakers?

Comment: So, nothing plays through the bluetooth and nothing plays from the AM/FM radio.  You do get signal through the aux and from bluetooth phone, do I have that right?  Is there any additional information you can provide regarding symptoms?  Have you tried deleting your phone regarding bluetooth synch out of the stereo  as well as deleting your stereo out of the phone and re-pairing them?

Comment: okey so its been 2 weeks. i tried every option on radio. even unpluged cables and still the same thing. i can connect my phone but no sound coming out of the speakers. no music on fm/am aux or bluetooth, ONLY bluetooth calls work and the speakers magically work. WEIRD!  i paired , unpaired, tried other devices, deleted devices of the radio as well. NO mods all stock.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

**Re-pair your phone with your car**

Goto your phone and delete your car as an audio device.

Goto your car stereo and delete your phone as a source device.

Re-pair your phone and your car and see what happens.

Seems to be an effective fix for me when I occasionally encounter this issue.

Comment: Is that repair by re-pair? :o)

Comment: tired it bro and nothing. silence. no music through am/fm aux or bluetooth, only a phone call goes through the speakers. only a phone call and all speakers work all of the sudden

Comment: That's nuts.  You should down vote me though.   Was worth a try in the troubleshooting process I guess.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

No signals on FM or AM ?  How is the antenna connection? If it is a recent model car the radio antenna is in the rear window and the connection is near the upper left hand side. You would probably have to remove a piece of molding to get at it. The antenna itself looks like a piece of the the rear window defroster only with a few lines(3 or 4) . It is connected to a inline amplifier.

Comment: If the antenna was disconnected, there should still be sound (static), Right? The OP even said Bluetooth and AUX inputs gave no sound.

Answer (score -1):

If all speakers suddenly stopped working, it is probably the amplifier. We had a leak in the car (likely through the sunroof which is another issue. The drainage needs to be cleaned out. Our dealer did it for $250. Hopefully now the leak is gone.) The amplifier is located under the passenger front seat, which is where the water from the leak collected, shorting the amp. The model number for our 2014 Outback amplifier is 86221AJ21A. However, once you locate the amp, you will see the model number right on it. Dealership was going to charge $750 for parts and labor. I bought a used one on Ebay for $150 and installed it myself. Needed a small Allen wrench and a small socket wrench to get the old one out and replace with the new one. (I don't know the sizes and felt lucky that I actually had the right ones.) It was a bit uncomfortable but very doable.